# accessing json in php sent by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

In `js` file I'm sending json object to php file but i don't know how to access to sent object.

first line in code below give me that:`{"id":1,"email":"asd@qwe.co.uk","password":"xxxx","location":"London"}`

**js file**

```
    app.showAlert(JSON.stringify(profile));

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"http://www.domain.co.uk/test-login.php",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: { data: JSON.stringify(profile) },
        success:function(json){
            // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
            app.showAlert(JSON.stringify(json), "Login ok");
        },
        error:function(){
            app.showAlert("Login faild", "Wrong username or password. Please try again.");
        },
    });
```

**php file:**

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$ret=$_GET['data'];

$ret=json_decode($ret, true);

echo '['.json_encode($ret[0]).']';

?>
```

Php is test, because i want to check if user pass correct details, then I will return json object with `'loggedin' => 1` or so, if not `0`

I also tried to access to this object by `$ret=$_GET['profile'];`, but it didn't help.

My question is: how to pass json object and access to it in php.

Comment: What does the output give you? What does the output of a print_r give you?

Comment: where exactly i should use `print_r`? the problem is that i cant check step by step what is going on, because if i dont receive json object I get msg `Login faild`.

Comment: The basic idea to print out a description of what you are getting to better figure out what is going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify both the ajax and PHP to get it to do what you want. I've changed the Javascript to test for the success/fail within the success function. IF you are returning JSON from PHP, then you don't want to be handling the failed password in the error event.

For the PHP you seem to be getting the input and output mixed up. As you can see the input is decoded into the `$data` variable, and the output is an array in `$output` until it gets encoded and output.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"http://www.domain.co.uk/test-login.php",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { data: JSON.stringify(profile) },
    success:function(json){
        // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
        if(json.loggedin == '1'){
            alert("logged in");
        } else {
            alert("failed to login");
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$output = array('loggedin' => 0);
$data = json_decode($_GET['data']);

// this shows how to access the data
if($data->email == 'asd@qwe.co.uk' && $data->password = '1234')
{
    $output['loggedin'] = '1';
}

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($output);
```